# c# Error as threw an exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException'

Tags: c#

Please help me. How can I remove that Error?

Here I have two classes:

```
 public class Users
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; } 
       public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public String Username { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
public class Role
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }  
        public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Here i wrote Simple Linq Query for Finding Result

```
 enum TypeofEmp{
                Admin=100,
                HttpRequest=101,
                Devoloper=102
        };
         public Users GetUsers(string Uname, string psw)
                {

                    var x = (from n in db.Users
                            where n.Username == Uname && n.Password == psw
                            select n).FirstOrDefault();
                    if(x!=null){
                ICollection<Role> role = new List<Role>();

                        int RoleId = x.RoleId;
                var RoleNmae   =  Enum.GetName(typeof(TypeofEmp), RoleId);    
                Role dd = new Role(); dd.RoleId = RoleId;  dd.RoleName = RoleNmae;
 Users users = new Users();
                users.Roles = role;
                    }       
                    return x;
```

Here i'm Getting Error as

> 'x.Roles' threw an exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `Users.RoleId` property, but that does not exist. You only have a `Roles` property, which has a list of roles (meaning one user may have multiple roles assigned).

```
foreach ( var role in x.Roles )
{
   //do something with role.RoleId
}
```

As a tip, I would rename the `Users` class o `User`, because now it is quite confusing, as you refer to a single user as `Users`.

Also, in the code you are creating `dd` variable with the role instance, but you are not using it anywhere. I am not sure this is what you want.

Comment: i habe RoleId By mistake it was missed

Comment: But in your code it does not seem you are accessing `x.Roles` anywhere. On which line does the exception happen?

Comment: can i store values Like  ICollection<Role> role = new List<Role>(); and then assign                 users.Roles = role;
how can its posible

Comment: Yes, that should be possible